# Exception when use future and promise in the same thread

Tags: c++, c++20

I got an exception when using a future and a promise in the same thread, while using c++20.

The exception is throwed when `prom.set_value(111);`

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Unknown error -1
```

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::promise<int> prom;
  std::future<int> fut = prom.get_future();
  std::cout << "1 ok" << std::endl;
  prom.set_value(111);
  std::cout << "2 ok" << std::endl;
  std::cout << fut.get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Run the above code on https://onlinegdb.com/gZp3cOOvj

Comment: What line threw the exception?

Comment: You should specify `-pthread` flag to enable multi-thread.

Comment: `  prom.set_value(111);` this line @NicolBolas

Comment: I test it on onlinegdb. No need to specify `-pthread` flag. @康桓瑋

Comment: If you specify `-pthread`, you will get [what you expect](https://onlinegdb.com/mpOcosgZB). So I'm wondering why you think it doesn't need to be specified?

Comment: @康桓瑋 I test your code and its result is as you said. I just run another test forked from `https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future` with a little modification. I do not specify `-pthread` and it works. https://onlinegdb.com/mLyXkx5S7

Comment: @康桓瑋 I still get the exception in the code you posted.